# Maven Jenkins job skips all modules if one fails to build

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, module

In Jenkins, I have a Maven project with the following structure:

```
x proftaakmaven
    - AutosimulatieSysteem
    - LandenMonitoringSysteem
    - PolitieSysteem
    x Verplaatsingssysteem
        - VerplaatsingREST
        - VerplaatsingSOAP
        - VerplaatsingCommon
        - VerplaatsingenRabbitMQ
        - RabbitMQ-Proof-of-Concept
        - VerplaatsingenRabbitMQTestClient
```

The Maven reactor constructs this building order:

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] AutoSimulatie
[INFO] LandenMonitorSysteem
[INFO] PolitieSysteem
[INFO] VerplaatsingenSysteem
[INFO] VerplaatsingenCommon
[INFO] VerplaatsingenREST
[INFO] VerplaatsingenSOAP
[INFO] RabbitMQ-Proof-of-Concept
[INFO] VerplaatsingenRabbitMQ
[INFO] VerplaatsingenRabbitMQTestClient
[INFO] proftaakmaven
```

However, due to a current failure in 'LandenMonitorSysteem' source code, Maven fails on building the other modules as well. This makes the Jenkins job fail.

I have tried running Maven with --fail-never and --fail-at-end. But neither seem to have any effect.

How would I be able to continue building all the modules, even if one fails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was the way that I provided the argument. In Jenkins 2.0, the job should be configured like this :

[The settings inside the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1lQ5.png)

Answer (score 0):

`--fail-at-end` should be the thing to use.

If that doesn't work you could use `-pl` to specify the list of working projects.

If you use the `-am` flag as well you can specify the target you are interested in building and Maven will calculate the dependency tree for you.

I.E. `mvn clean install -pl VerplaatsingenRabbitMQTestClient -am`